# Riemann integral of a function of the Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

$\bullet$ Find mean and variance of the next stochastical process, and prove it is a second order stationary process:

$Y(t)=\displaystyle\int_{t}^{t+1}(W(s)-W(t))\;ds$

---

To obtain the mean, as $W(s)-W(t)\thicksim N(0,s-t)$, we have that $\mathbb{E}[Y(t)]=\displaystyle\int_{t}^{t+1}\mathbb{E}[W(s)-W(t)]\;ds=\displaystyle\int_{t}^{t+1}0\; ds=0$

To prove it is a second order stationary process, I know I have to show that $\mathbb{E}[Y(t)^2]<\infty$.

As  $\mathbb{E}[Y(t)^2]= \Gamma_Y (t,t)$.I think all would be done if I had the covariance, $\Gamma_Y(s,t)$.

But how can I calculate that covariance?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s \leq t$. First of all, we note that by the independence of the increments,

$$\mathbb{E}((W_u-W_s) \cdot (W_v-W_t)) = 0$$

for any $s \leq u \leq t \leq v$. Therefore, Fubini's theorem shows that $\mathbb{E}(Y_t \cdot Y_s)=0$ for any $s \leq t-1$. For $t-1 \leq s \leq t$, we find

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(Y_t \cdot Y_s) &= \int_t^{t+1} \int_t^{s+1} \mathbb{E}\big(((W_u-W_t)+(W_t - W_s)) \cdot (W_v-W_t)\big) \, du \, dv\\ &=\int_t^{t+1} \int_t^{s+1} \mathbb{E}\big((W_u - W_t) \cdot (W_v-W_t)\big) \, du \, dv \\ &=\int_0^{1} \int_0^{(s+1)-t} \mathbb{E}\big((W_{u+t} - W_t) \cdot (W_{v+t}-W_t)\big) \, du \, dv\end{align*}$$

using that $W_v-W_t$ and $W_t-W_s$ are independent random variables with mean $0$. Note that $B_u := W_{t+u}-W_t$, $u\geq0$, is a Brownian motion and therefore we find

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_t \cdot Y_s) =  \int_0^{s+1-t} \int_0^1 \underbrace{\text{cov}(B_u,B_v)}_{\min\{u,v\}} \, dv \, du$$

The latter integral can be easily computated.

Comment: The remark that "Bu:=Wu+t−Wt, u≥0, is again a Brownian motion" could be used from the start, leading to some simplifications.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I understand everything except how you get that $\text{cov}(B_u,B_v) = \max\{u,v\}$... 
I know that $\Gamma_{W}(t,s)=\min\{t,s\}$, but i'm not sure if you deduced that from this. Could you detail this point a bit more?

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman Sorry, you are right, of course, it should read "min" instead of "max". ($B$ is a Brownian motion and therefore the covariance equals $\min\{u,v\}$.)

Comment: @Did I've rewritten my answer, but I fail to see why it should make things easier if I introduce the restarted Brownian motion right from the start.

Comment: I'm curious too about how much this could be simplified using Did's observation. But I understand the way you solved it. Thanks a lot, saz!